# Best way to read an HDFS file into a string?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

Currently, I have the following code.

```
        try
        {           
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
            byte[] buffer=new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(new Path(fname));
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                builder.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            in.close();

            return builder.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
```

As you can see, I have allocated 4096 bytes to the buffer. Now, since an HDFS block is 64 MB, would it better to allocate a buffer of size 64 MB? What would be the most efficient way to write this, given that my HDFS file size > 64 MB.

Comment: If you have > 64MB, you'll have to allocate that much one way or the other.  If you know the size and allocate up front you can spare yourself the reallocation.

Comment: Is reallocation the only penalty?

Comment: Don't know.  That's all I can think of based on the code you posted.  I don't know what happens to that string when you're done reading it in.

Comment: Since you tagged the question with `apache-spark` - why don't you read the file into RDD/Dataframe using Spark's convenient APIs (e.g. `sc.textFile("hdfs://...")`)?